# How to make one WordPress page show differently on a mobile device

Tags: wordpress

I have a specific WordPress page that I need to show in a larger font when it's viewed on mobile devices. I thought about doing this:

```
@media handheld { /* rules for handheld devices */ }
```

...but don't see where I can throw that into my page's header. What's the simplest way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: thats a css rule so you would need it between `<style></style>`

Comment: You can also edit the Style.css of the theme you are using so that it is universal throughout your template

Comment: Exactly, David. I just don't know how to do that in WordPress. When I edit the page, all I see is the code within the <body>.

Comment: My preference, Robert, is just to touch the specific page in question. If that's not possible, I'll look into changing the global stylesheet.

Comment: open the header.php page if you want inline styles, meaning put it between the `<head></head>` or add it to the style.css page

Comment: Okay. So it sounds like I'm in for a global change. That's okay, I guess. I'll just throw some IDs where I need them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target a specific page in wordpress you can do this.

in your **header.php** add this code instead of the opening **`<body>`** tag

```
<body <?php $id = get_the_ID(); $title = str_replace(' ','-', strtolower(get_the_title($id)));  body_class($title); ?>>
```

this gets the title of the page makes it all lowercase and add dashes instead of spaces.

so if you had a page called **The Neighborhood** you now have a class called **`.the-neighborhood`**

target it like so in your main **style.css** page

```
@media handheld { 
   body.the-neighborhood header {
      /*header styles for only the neighborhood page */
    }
}
```

Comment: David, This looks like a good solution. Unfortunately, the company I'm doing this for now just wants me to move the WordPress pages over to their ASP site, so your solution won't really apply anymore. However, since I think it's a good answer to my question, I will definitely give you credit for it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/assets/css/small-device.css"

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/